# python - parsing file to json

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have some log files from where I want to extract data and export it to json.

Each time pattern is found the variables timestamp, line, frequence, crossbow, numberIt get a value, i do:

`stringToJson.append({timestamp:00000, line:RRL, frequence:3434Hz, crossbow:TKESS44,  numberIt: 2})`
Then I dump it:
`json.dump(stringToJson, outfile)`

the result is
`[{timestamp:00000, line:RRL, frequence:3434Hz, crossbow:TKESS44,  numberIt: 2},{timestamp:00000, line:RRL, frequence:3434Hz, crossbow:TKESS43,  numberIt: 3},..., {timestamp:00001, line:CCL, frequence:8834Hz, crossbow:T1LS44,  numberIt: 20}, {timestamp:00001, line:CCL, frequence:8834Hz, crossbow:T1LS45,  numberIt: 21},..., ...]`.

I would like it:
[{00000: {"RRL":{"3434Hz":{"TKESS44":5}, {"TKESS44":5}}, {00001: {"CCL":{"8834Hz":{"T1LS44":20},{"T1LS45":20}}}}

How can I do that?

Cheers,

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your python code does exactly what you ask it for; you pass it a dictionary (with keys like timestamp, line, and "frequence" and assigning values to it) and it gives you a "flat" dictionary in return.

Let's suppose your VALUES of variables correspond to the names and you can somewhat pass them like: `line_value`, `frequence_value`, `timestamp_value`, `crossbow_value`, `numberIt_value`.

For example:

```
timestamp_value = "00000"
line_value = "RRL"
frequence_value = "3434Hz"
crossbow_value = "TKESS44"
numberIt_value = 2
stringToJson.append({str(timestamp_value) : {str(line_value) : {frequence_value : {str(crossbow_value) : int(numberIt_value)}}} })
```

Gives

```
[{'00000': {'RRL': {'3434Hz': {'TKESS44': 2}}}}]
```

This does what you want, remember that that way you don't keep the keys in the dictionary, so you need to "know" the JSON structure you are building.